# How to enable Kafka connector status in wso2 esb 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We can manually enable Kafka connector in wso2 esb or any other connector status but i would like to know is there any option where it can be updated in any configuration file. Basically I am looking for an option to enable the kafka flag in any wso2 esb configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an option to enable it by configuration file

- Visit to
  /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/imports
- add {org.wso2.carbon.connector}kafkaTransport.xml file

**{org.wso2.carbon.connector}kafkaTransport.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<import xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    name="kafkaTransport"
    package="org.wso2.carbon.connector"
    status="enabled"/>
```